# Unity IOS Crash

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash, ios14

I have such a problem, I put together a build for ios in unity.

When I run a app via XCode:

-iPad Mini 2 (IOS 12+) starts up and works
-iPhone 10 (IOS 14+) starts up and works

When I submit the build to TestFly

-iPad Mini 2 (IOS 12+) starts up and works
-iPhone 10 (IOS 14+) does not start and crashes

The application opens, freezes and crashes.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, <RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:process-launch watchdog transgression: application<com.erow.whatcraft>:5220 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: process-launch | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 12.560 (user 12.560, system 0.000), 10% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.095, 0% CPU" | ) reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cb171e7c __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc481fc _dlock_wait + 56
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc48128 _dispatch_once_wait + 124
3   UIKitCore                       0x000000019f642830 -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext] + 152
4   UIKitCore                       0x000000019f642b7c -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader applicationInitializationContext] + 32
5   UIKitCore                       0x000000019f629814 -[_UIScreenInitialDisplayConfigurationLoader initialDisplayContext] + 180
6   UIKitCore                       0x000000019f629b00 +[UIScreen initialize] + 128
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b1afac40 CALLING_SOME_+initialize_METHOD + 24
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b1b014bc initializeNonMetaClass + 788
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b1b02a9c initializeAndMaybeRelock+ 39580 (objc_class*, objc_object*, mutex_tt<false>&, bool) + 280
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b1b11b74 lookUpImpOrForward + 992
11  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b1afb644 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68
12  UnityFramework                  0x00000001005cd420 0x1004c0000 + 1102880
13  UnityFramework                  0x00000001005cc6dc 0x1004c0000 + 1099484
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc4781c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc490b4 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
16  UnityFramework                  0x00000001005cc6c0 0x1004c0000 + 1099456
17  UnityFramework                  0x00000001006759a4 0x1004c0000 + 1792420
18  UnityFramework                  0x00000001006747d4 0x1004c0000 + 1787860
19  UnityFramework                  0x0000000100674674 0x1004c0000 + 1787508
20  UnityFramework                  0x000000010069f0d4 0x1004c0000 + 1962196
21  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001b1b0a660 load_images + 924
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc9b3b4 invocation function for block in dyld3::AllImages::runInitialzersBottomUp+ 78772 (dyld3::closure::Image const*) + 224
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc8b948 dyld3::closure::Image::forEachImageToInitBefore(void + 14664 (unsigned int, bool&) block_pointer) const + 104
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc9bf30 dyld3::AllImages::loadImage+ 81712 (Diagnostics&, char const*, unsigned int, dyld3::closure::DlopenClosure const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*) + 844
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc9b9c0 dyld3::AllImages::dlopen+ 80320 (Diagnostics&, char const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*, bool) + 936
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc9d928 dyld3::dlopen_internal+ 88360 (char const*, int, void*) + 372
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc8eecc dlopen_internal+ 28364 (char const*, int, void*) + 152
28  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019cfadd00 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadFramework + 140
29  CoreFoundation                  0x000000019cf7cae8 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 388
30  Foundation                      0x000000019e2ee930 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 424
31  Whatcraft                       0x00000001002a3d54 0x10029c000 + 32084
32  Whatcraft                       0x00000001002a3dfc 0x10029c000 + 32252
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc89cf8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e8bc5744 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.uikit.applicationSupportClient
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001cb171124 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e8bc21e4 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 88
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e8bc2130 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 232
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc9d800 dyld3::dlopen_internal+ 88064 (char const*, int, void*) + 76
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019cc8eecc dlopen_internal+ 28364 (char const*, int, void*) + 152
5   SoftLinking                     0x00000001e095df50 _sl_dlopen_audited + 52
6   BoardServices                   0x00000001b667d2f0 __getRBSServiceInitializeSymbolLoc_block_invoke + 84
7   BoardServices                   0x00000001b667a8d0 __34+[BSServiceManager sharedInstance]_block_invoke + 900
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc4781c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc490b4 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
10  BoardServices                   0x00000001b667a548 +[BSServiceManager sharedInstance] + 84
11  BoardServices                   0x00000001b6672b0c +[BSServiceConnection _connectionWithEndpoint:clientContextBuilder:] + 324
12  UIKitServices                   0x00000001a1004c24 __44-[UISApplicationSupportClient _remoteTarget]_block_invoke + 208
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc4781c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc56910 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60
15  UIKitServices                   0x00000001a1004b0c -[UISApplicationSupportClient _remoteTarget] + 184
16  UIKitServices                   0x00000001a1004358 -[UISApplicationSupportClient applicationInitializationContextWithParameters:] + 192
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000019f6429b0 __63-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext]_block_invoke_2 + 228
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000019f6428c0 __UIAPPLICATION_IS_LOADING_INITIALIZATION_INFO_FROM_THE_SYSTEM__ + 28
19  UIKitCore                       0x000000019f642898 __63-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext]_block_invoke + 100
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc4781c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc490b4 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
22  UIKitCore                       0x000000019f642830 -[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader _loadInitializationContext] + 152
23  UIKitCore                       0x000000019f642b40 __70-[_UIApplicationConfigurationLoader startPreloadInitializationContext]_block_invoke + 28
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc45a84 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc4781c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc5910c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 688
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019cc597d8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e8bbe768 _pthread_wqthread + 216
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001e8bc574c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0xfffffffffffffffc   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000002005   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000023
    x8: 0x0000000000002107   x9: 0x0000000000002004  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x000000000000000f
   x12: 0x00000000009ad0db  x13: 0x03000001ff5ded89  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x00000001ff5ded88
   x16: 0x0000000000000203  x17: 0x000000019f642834  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x00000001ff5f0940  x21: 0x0000000001000002  x22: 0x0000000000002005  x23: 0x0000000000000008
   x24: 0x0000000000000008  x25: 0x00000001ff57fa7c  x26: 0x000000010042b9a0  x27: 0x0000000281f8c900
   x28: 0x000000028398cba0   fp: 0x000000016fb5dbf0   lr: 0x000000019cc481fc
    sp: 0x000000016fb5dbd0   pc: 0x00000001cb171e7c cpsr: 0x00000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```